# C++ nodejs addon implementation throwing v8.h errors but is working fine on the nodejs side

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm dealing with a simple example about a Nodejs addon in C++, taken from the [official documentation about Nodejs addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) (it's not that big of a thing).

The example works fine when built using `node-gyp build` and the execution from the nodejs side is totally ok. However, i'm getting a bunch of errors in the C++ side related to the v8.h file. These errors aren't helping because they aren't letting me continue my work on the C++ side.

They are probably some linking errors since i can't find the libv8.a file, but here are some examples to see by yourself:

```
‘ArrayBufferCreationMode’ is not a class or namespace
‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
call to ‘v8::IndexedPropertyHandlerConfiguration::IndexedPropertyHandlerConfiguration(v8::IndexedPropertyGetterCallback, v8::IndexedPropertySetterCallback, v8::IndexedPropertyQueryCallback, v8::IndexedPropertyDeleterCallback, v8::IndexedPropertyEnumeratorCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyHandlerFlags)’ uses the default argument for parameter 7, which is not yet defined
expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
```

And many others, all located in the v8.h.

I tried building the v8 library without success, but i'm wondering if the problem is really from that.

**EDIT 1**

I forgot to mention that i'm using eclipse-cpp for working on the C++ project. What I need to do is to use a `.cpp` from that project as an entry to the Nodejs addon and not the whole project, but the errors are preventing me from using other classes and files.

My GCC is now under the 4.9.3 version and i have the clang-3.5 installed. Still i don't know what to do now because the errors are still there.

Comment: Upgrade your compiler. You need at least gcc 4.8.5 or clang 3.4 or VS2013. Also, use a module like `nan` to handle node/V8 compatibility issues.

Comment: @mscdex Thanks for your response, i've updated my question for more info.